# How to setup Xdebug with Brackets for debugging PHP?

Tags: php, xdebug, adobe-brackets

I have been reading for a few days and tried different things, but in the end, nothing seems to work. I am running Apache, Xdebug 3.0.2, PHP 7.4.3, and Brackets. Running in Ubuntu 20.04.

These are my php.ini files (CLI and Apache2) and xdebug.ini

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

My preferences .json file in Brackets:

```
"php": {
        "enablePhpTooling": true,
        "memoryLimit": "4095M",
        "validateOnType": "false"
    },
```

I have installed PHP debugger in Brackets and Xdebug helper as extension in Chrome.

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Looks like the use of `v2.x` settings with `v3.x`. The [configuration settings](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) have [changed in the 3.x](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) version.

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly that. Just rolled back to v2.x and it is working well

Comment: @AndrésGalán Why not just change just A FEW parameter names and use LATEST Xdebug version instead (v2 is no longer supported).